# Reading DS18b20 sensors using ESP-IDF using a ESP32 with a 26 MHx XTAL

Tags: esp32

I'm able to read DS18B20 sensors using the example code provided in this [repository](https://github.com/DavidAntliff/esp32-ds18b20-example).

It works well using a standard Espressif ESP32-WROOM-32 (aka ESP32-DevKitC), which uses a 40 MHz XTAL.

I'm not able to run the same example using an [Allnet-IOT-WLAN](https://www.allnet.de/lp/iot-wlan-display/), which uses a 26 MHz XTAL.

I suspect that the problem is related with [RMT initialization](https://github.com/DavidAntliff/esp32-owb/blob/bc69da51bfa766d8023e82cd214ac61349960095/owb_rmt.c). The initialization is using:

```
rmt_tx.clk_div = 80;
```

I've tried different settings for `clk_div` with no luck.

Does anyone know how to use the DS18B20 sensor with ESP-IDF, using a board with a 26 MHz XTAL, instead of more standard 40 MHz one?

#### ESP32-WROOM-32 output (working)

```
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
Find devices:
  0 : d4000008e40d7428
  1 : f8000008e3632528
Found 2 devices
Device 1502162ca5b2ee28 is not present

Temperature readings (degrees C): sample 1
  0: 22.3    0 errors
  1: 21.8    0 errors

Temperature readings (degrees C): sample 2
  0: 22.3    0 errors
  1: 21.9    0 errors
```

#### Allnet-IOT-WLAN output (not working)

```
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
Find devices:
Found 0 devices
E (6780) owb_rmt: rx_items == 0
E (6880) owb_rmt: rx_items == 0
E (6980) owb_rmt: rx_items == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in the RMT initialization using different XTAL clock frequencies.

```
D (2319) rmt: Rmt Tx Channel 1|Gpio 25|Sclk_Hz 80000000|Div 80|Carrier_Hz 0|Duty 35
D (2319) intr_alloc: Connected src 47 to int 13 (cpu 0)
D (2319) rmt: Rmt Rx Channel 0|Gpio 25|Sclk_Hz 80000000|Div 80|Thresold 77|Filter 30
```

Both use the same 80 MHx source.

I was using a wrong pinout diagram. I've tested the RMT with a more [simple example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/peripherals/rmt_tx) and I found out that the pinout was wrong.

The DS18b20 sensors works well with a 26 MHz XTAL with the [esp32-ds18b20](https://github.com/DavidAntliff/esp32-ds18b20) library.